Log4j2.properties deleting the files during rollover of older logs
we have a project where it tries to rollover older files but it deletes the other files which shouldn't be part of deletion as per the configuration.
can you please review the configuration and advise if anything is abnormal.
status = warn
name= LoggerProject

# Log files location
property.basePath= .

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= Log.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= Log_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath} 
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Delete all files older than 30 days
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.condition.glob = */Log*.log.gz
# Configure root logger
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger

Reviewed the configuration from Log4j2 official community as per the provided documentation. Requesrt some expert advise here.

OP's review comment:
Project uses log4j-api, log4j-core, log4j-jcl version2.17.1

Can you explain more what you expect? Which files are deleted when?
